# Не отображается контакт форм 7 WordPress на странице

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php /* Template Name: Шаблон с калькулятором 3 */ ?>
<?
  get_header();
  while (have_posts()) :
    the_post();
    $default_bg = get_bloginfo("template_url") . "/img/print_bg.jpg";
    $background = (get_field("img")) ? get_field("img") : $default_bg ;
?>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="info-block">
      <img class="size-full wp-image-6 alignleft" style="float: left; margin: 20px;" src="https://static.mk.ru/upload/entities/2017/09/16/articles/detailPicture/1c/27/24/f6/7e913539e32c7d8d121cab3705bc2cfd.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="220" />
      <h3 class="info-block-title">
        Заголовок
      </h3>
      <h4 class="info-block-title">
        Артикул
      </h4>
      <p class="info-block-text">
        текст
      </p>
      <p><input name="card-size" type="radio" value="nedzen"> 10x15</p>
      <p><input name="card-size" type="radio" value="dzen"> 15x20</p>
      <p><input name="card-size" type="radio" value="pdzen"> 20x30</p>
      <div class="number">
        <span class="minus" style="display:inline-block; padding:5px;">-</span>
        <input type="text" value="1" size="5"/>
        <span class="plus" style="display:inline-block; padding:5px;">+</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#card-popup-form" class="popup-form-btn">Заказать</a>



  </div>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/jаvascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('.minus').click(function () {
                var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
                count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
                $input.val(count);
                $input.change();
                return false;
            });
            $('.plus').click(function () {
                var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
                $input.change();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
<?
  endwhile;
  get_footer();
?>
```

Почему не отображается контакт форма 7 на странице? Вставляю шорткод в редактор страницы, вкладка "визуально". На станице присутствует другой контент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой-другой? Дайте конкретику.

Comment: я создал страницу на основе шаблона, который редактирую через ftp и все что я добавляю в шаблон отображается на странице. теперь мне нужно добавить на страницу форму. я добавил шорткод в редактор страницы но на странице форму не видно. может нужно добавлять как-то иначе?

Comment: контент: картинка и несколько абзацев текста

Comment: А шорткод? Отображается в виде шорткода или вообще никак? Дайте картинки уже того, что в админке и что видите на сайте.

Comment: ошибка в инспекторе - это какая-то картинка не подгружается

Comment: Скорее всего, верстка кривая. Радио-кнопки и инпут кол-ва отображаются, а дальше всё пропало. Раскройте в dev tools их `<p>`, правой кнопкой - Scroll Into View, посмотрите, где содержимое.

Comment: всё что я добавил в шаблон отображается, а затем идёт футер. где должна отобразиться форма?после хедера ли перед футером.  подскажите можно ли и как подключить форму в код файла шаблона.

Comment: на скрине всё раскрыто в инспекторе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78927/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

зайдите на тот файл где вы хотите вставить шорткод.
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[somename]'); ?>`

[somename] - замените на фаш шорткод.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пояснений к коду - так будет понятнее что он делает и как этот код отвечает на вопрос)

Comment: Всем спасибо. У меня не работал вывод. добавил в файл вывод the_content(); и всё отображается